# Is it possible to share subscribe event in rxjs6 and angular?

Tags: typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I have service class that simply calls an api. This service class is being consumed in a component. Is there a way for consuming component to know when the subscribe of the service api is complete?

Right now I am sending a callback function from consuming component to service.
The callback function is one of the parameter of subscribe function is what I understand.

```
class MyService {
constructor(httpClient: HTTPClient){}
fetchDetails (id, callback) {
 this.http.get('my/api/endpoint/url').subscribe(
  response => {
    // do something with response
  }
  error => { //do some processing for error}
  () => callback() // called when subscribe is done
 )
}
}
class MyList {
 constructor(myservice: MyService){}

 getDetails (id) {
  this.myservice.fetchDetails(id, this.detailsFetched);
 }
 detailsFetched () {
  // subscribe complete
  // do some processing like route to a state
 }
}
```

This currently works for me but somehow I feel that there must be better way of doing what I want. Since I am newbie to rxjs I am not able to understand how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct, as an alternative I can suggest more declarative RxJS way of writing something like that.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { shareReplay, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

class MyService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fetchDetails(id): Observable<any> {
    const stream$ = this.http
      .get(`my/api/endpoint/url/${id}`)
      .pipe(shareReplay());

    stream$.subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('completed');
      },
    );

    return stream$;
  }
}

class MyList {
  constructor(private myservice: MyService) {}

  private getDetails(id) {
    this.myservice
      .fetchDetails(id)
      .pipe(finalize(() => this.detailsFetched()))
      .subscribe();
  }

  private detailsFetched() {
    // subscribe complete
    // do some processing like route to a state
  }
}
```

To summarize, you can see that I am returning `Observable` from `fetchDetails()`, which is created with `shareReplay()`. What `shareReplay()` does is that it will only create 1 network call and share it to whoever subscribes to the source observable, then if someone subscribes later when observable is finished, it will replay so that later subscribers will receive same events.

Also have a look at `getDetails` where I use `finalize()` operator to do exactly what you want. **The callback passed to finalize operator will be called when the source Observable is completed.**

Comment: Goga Koreli thanks for the reply. I had read about shareReplay but then I thought that there might something else available. I thought it should be easy as sharing promises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rxjs operator take within a pipe. That way you only subscribe to the first event that is emitted from your observable.

```
fetchDetails (id, callback) {
 this.http.get('my/api/endpoint/url').pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
  response => {
    // do something with response
  }
  error => { //do some processing for error}
  () => callback() // called when subscribe is done
 )
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I am not sure how that helps the cause. Basically what i want is to do
`this.myservice.fetchDetails(id).subscribe(done => { //subscribe is done, do your work here})`
Right now only way to do it for me is to send a callback function that will be called when fetchDetails get completed.